# Custom Credential Provider cannot loaded

Tags: windows, credential-providers

I applied the Credential Provider Sample provided by MS(https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-classic-samples) on Windows10 in VMware.

But there is nothing changed.

Below is what I applied.

Please let me know if I missed something or did something wrong.

Thanks in adavance.

1. I placed the .dll file in the C:/Windows/System32.
2. I ran the Register.reg below.

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Authentication\Credential Providers\{5fd3d285-0dd9-4362-8855-e0abaacd4af6}]
@="SampleV2CredentialProvider"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{5fd3d285-0dd9-4362-8855-e0abaacd4af6}]
@="SampleV2CredentialProvider"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{5fd3d285-0dd9-4362-8855-e0abaacd4af6}\InprocServer32]
@="SampleV2CredentialProvider.dll"
"ThreadingModel"="Apartment"
```

3. To apply my credential provider as the default credential provider, I entered the GUID into 'Assign a default credential provider'.
   [image]
4. Nothing changed after reboot.
   [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by changing the value of **AutoAdminLogon** to 1 located in **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon**.